# How to get the minimun ditsance from an obstacle

Tags: ros, gazebo, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working with gazebo and I would like to detect the minimum distance between my robot and an obstacle. The model of the robot is an urdf file. What is the best sensor to use? How do I "attach" it to the robot and how do I get the data?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11147/how-to-get-the-minimun-ditsance-from-an-obstacle/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-09-07**:
Do you need 2D range data or 3D? What's the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing you need is to segment out the obstacle from the other objects in the environment. This might or might not be tricky, depending on the environment and the sensors you want to use.

You can either use a laser or a generic pointcloud (coming from a stereo/range camera or a tilting laser). The latter is the most generic and you can always convert a laser message to a pointcloud. However if you are interested in a gazebo simulation only, then a laser will be easier.

Then for every point in the pointcloud, you can transform it to the coordinate system you prefer (e.g. for the PR2 it would be baselink) and a simple euclidean distance will give you the answer.

If you are using the laser only, then the minimum in the range field of the laser message will give you the closest point.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-06-30**:
Hello. Im trying to do the same with a laser. I wont to know how to work with straight lines in laser scan massages. Because the points on the longest straight lines is likely the wall and point not on the longest straight line the msg are likely on the other object. Any help??

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2013-07-09**:
@Astronaut you should post this as a new question, and check if somebody has not asked the same before. Your problem is very common, I bet you'll find a solution.